# Grid for copying photos from laptop

Tags: tool-fabrication, reference

I want to use my photos to paint from. I would like to know how to find a grid for my screen to square off my photo. This would aid in transferring it to a canvas or paper.
I've tried to find a photo editor app, etc. but none offer grid overlays I guess you'd call them.  I'm an artist, not so smart about computers and what's available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't really allow for product recommendations, but you can make your own grid overlays:

- Buy a sheet of flexible plastic, and use a permanent marker and ruler to create a grid with your preferred scale, and simply put it up against your monitor.
  Usually it can rest against the borders of the screen, but a little tape will definitely hold it in place.
- In an image editor like Photoshop or the free open-source [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) you can:

  - add guidelines;
  - (add a transparent layer and) add lines on top of the reference image (and save that layer to use it whenever you need it);
  - make use of the feature to show grids (the size can be adjusted);
  - find premade grids on transparent background images [online](https://www.ecosia.org/images?q=grid%20transparent).

Comment: I'm not at my pc now, but I think the gimp can show a grid as an option.

Comment: No problem - and I can confirm it's under View|Show Grid, configured with Image|Configure Grid.  You can set the defaults in preferences.

Comment: Thank you so much. Maybe the most obvious is the best solution. I will check out Gimp again and them make my own I think....

Comment: I think a faster way to add lines, cut, and + might be using google drawings, I sometimes use it and it perfectly works